# setting a program as my login shell

Tags: c, shell, unix, authentication

Can I set a small program that I wrote as my login shell? Instead of a regular login shell like bash? I tried googling but could not find any useful information. Any pointer is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure this is a good idea?  Once you change your login shell to this "small program", unless that program is itself a working shell, you won't be able to change it back, because you won't be able to run the `chsh` command.  How does just running the program after you login, or invoking it from your `$HOME/.bash_profile` or other init file, not meet your requirements?

Comment: Yes, I am quite sure what I am getting into :) thanks for the concern though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
chsh -s /usr/bin/foo someuser
```

Or use `vipw` to edit `/etc/passwd` (just don't edit it directly).

Comment: tbe vipw point is valid, but it should not be too dangerous, I think, because the shell info is only present in the /etc/passwd file, +1

Comment: True enough, but editing `/etc/passwd` directly is a bad habit to get into. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can change the login shell executable with the command `chsh` (change shell) or by manually editing the `/etc/passwd` file (the last value on the line is the login shell).

Editing the /etc/password file manually is discouraged, as 1) it requires root permission 2) the user base might not be local, but distributed using NIS, LDAP etc. and thus this will not work 3) chsh should work also in the case of a distributed user base.

As the question addresses unices, Solaris does not have this command and the only way you can mimic this behavior (without root access for which you can use `passwd -e`) is by executing the other shell from your `.profile` file.

Also, keep in mind that the custom shell binary must be present in `/etc/shells`, otherwise it will not work.

Comment: This is true if you are on a machine using local authentication.  Company/university/etc. computers will often use network services like LDAP for user information.